# postgresql 10 for Ubuntu 17.10 artful?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-10

Is PostgreSQL 10 available on Ubuntu 17.10 artful?

I checked that the folder on APT actually exists: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/artful-pgdg/10/

But after I do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ artful-pgdg main"
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
```

I get an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-10
```

The above steps worked for Ubuntu 16.04 (with `xenial-pgdg`), but not for 17.10.

Any pointers?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/ does not list Ubuntu 17.10  so I guess you need to download the RPMs manually, ask this on the Postgres mailing list or contact [the maintainers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt)

Comment: You can compile it yourself? It's a doddle! Did it today in 20 mins!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have replaced ***artful-pgdg*** with ***zesty-pgdg*** in */etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list* and it worked for me

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ

**I am using a non-LTS release of Ubuntu**

Non-LTS releases of Ubuntu are only added to the repository if the packages from the latest LTS release are incompatible with the release in question. Using the latest LTS release instead generally works, unless library dependencies cannot be fulfilled, in which case we will provide updated packages for the non-LTS release.